# How to delete an member variable consisting of an array of pointers

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-leaks

Good afternoon, I am trying to delete a C++ class member variable consisting of an array of pointers. Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
class NFA {
public:

    dict<tuple2<__ss_int, __ss_int> *, dict<str *, __shedskin__::set<tuple2<__ss_int, __ss_int> *> *> *> *transitions;

    auto_vector< dict<str *, set<tuple2<__ss_int, __ss_int> *> *> >   *tmpautovector;

    NFA() {} 
    ~NFA() { delete this->tmpautovector
    NFA(tuple2<__ss_int, __ss_int> *start_state) {
        this->__class__ = cl_NFA;
        __init__(start_state);
    }
    void *add_transition(tuple2<__ss_int, __ss_int> *src, str *input, tuple2<__ss_int, __ss_int> *dest);
}


void *NFA::add_transition(tuple2<__ss_int, __ss_int> *src, str *input, tuple2<__ss_int, __ss_int> *dest) {
     dict<str *, set<tuple2<__ss_int, __ss_int> *> *> *tmpdict;

    if ((!(this->transitions)->__contains__(src))) {
        tmpdict = new dict<str *, set<tuple2<__ss_int, __ss_int> *> *>();
        this->transitions->__setitem__(src, tmpdict);
        tmpautovector->push_back(tmpdict);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I am trying to use the auto_vector class to store an array of pointers. Here are some of the functions of the auto_vector class. The documentation for this class says that this is not a STL vector of auto_ptr's . The use of STL vectors to store auto_ptr's is strongly discouraged > I keep getting a segmentation fault when I access the auto_vector::operator member function > The GDB stack trace, shown below shows the segmentation fault. I am wondering whether it is possible to fix this segmentation fault or whether are better approaches to deleting member variables consisting of array of pointers. Thank you.

```
// auto_vector.h
// This file is (C) 2002-2004 Royce Mitchell III
// and released under the LGPL & BSD licenses

#ifndef AUTO_VECTOR_H
#define AUTO_VECTOR_H

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <memory>




template<class T>
class auto_vector
{
public:
    explicit auto_vector ( size_t capacity = 0 )
        : _arr(0), _capacity(0), _end(0)
    {
        if ( capacity != 0 )
            _arr =  new std::auto_ptr<T>[capacity];
        _capacity = capacity;
    }

    ~auto_vector()
    {
        delete []_arr;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return _end;
    }

    const std::auto_ptr<T>& operator [] ( size_t i ) 
        {
        return _arr[i];
    }

    std::auto_ptr<T>& operator [] ( size_t i )
        {
        return _arr[i];
    }

        void push_back ( std::auto_ptr<T>& p )
    {
        reserve ( _end + 1 );
        _arr[_end++] = p;
    }

        void push_back ( T * p )
    {
        reserve ( _end + 1 );
        std::auto_ptr<T> tmp(p);
        _arr[_end++] = tmp;
        //GCC is pedantic, this is an error.
        //_arr[_end++] = auto_ptr<T>(p);
    }

    void reserve ( size_t reqCapacity )
    {
        if ( reqCapacity <= _capacity )
            return;
        size_t newCapacity = 2 * _capacity;
        if ( reqCapacity > newCapacity )
            newCapacity = reqCapacity;
        // allocate new array
        std::auto_ptr<T> * arrNew = new std::auto_ptr<T> [newCapacity];
        // transfer all entries
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < _capacity; ++i )
            arrNew[i] = _arr[i];
        _capacity = newCapacity;
        // free old memory
        delete[] _arr;
        // substitute new array for old array
        _arr = arrNew;
    }

private:
    std::auto_ptr<T>  *_arr;
    size_t        _capacity;
    size_t        _end;
};

#endif//AUTO_VECTOR_H

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0806b85a in std::auto_ptr<__shedskin__::setentry<__shedskin__::tuple2<int, int>*> >::get (this=0x0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/memory:300
300           get() const throw() { return _M_ptr; }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0806b85a in std::auto_ptr<__shedskin__::setentry<__shedskin__::tuple2<int, int>*> >::get (this=0x0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/memory:300
#1  0x0806be61 in __shedskin__::set<__shedskin__::tuple2<int, int>*>::lookup (this=0x80a3c58, key=0x80a3c40, 
    hash=-1919631394) at ../Include/builtin.hpp:3223
#2  0x0806bfc7 in __shedskin__::set<__shedskin__::tuple2<int, int>*>::insert_key (this=0x80a3c58, key=0x80a3c40, 
    hash=-1919631394) at ../Include/builtin.hpp:3258
#3  0x080728ea in __shedskin__::set<__shedskin__::tuple2<int, int>*>::add (this=0x80a3c58, key=0x80a3c40)
    at ../Include/builtin.hpp:3278
#4  0x0806af0c in main (Argc_=<value optimized out>, Argv_=<value optimized out>) at ../Source/mdMatchupTest.cpp:93
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x0806be61 in __shedskin__::set<__shedskin__::tuple2<int, int>*>::lookup (this=0x80a3c58, key=0x80a3c40, 
    hash=-1919631394) at ../Include/builtin.hpp:3223
3223        setentry<T>* entry = table->operator[](i)->get(); // &table[i]
```

Comment: Who's code is this? I mean, both `auto_vector` and `NFA`? It's a mess!

Comment: Have you considered simply using a std::vector of boost::shared_ptrs, in place of a custom vector of auto_ptr's which have "curious ownership semantics"?

Comment: @wilhemtell , The auto_vector class code was released under a LGPL & BSD license in 2004. The NFA class code was generated by a Python to C++ converter program.

Comment: @Andy Thomas-Cramer, We cannot us boost at this time becuase we are still waiting for the latest Solaris, IBM AIX and HPUX licenses. I was wondering about your comment about curious ownership semantics. Do you think that is causing the segmentation fault? Is there a possible workaround while we wait for possible approval of the UNIX licenses? I am considering using fixed size arrays of tuple2 classes to avoid the new and delete segmentation faults. Thank you.

Comment: Assignment of auto_ptr transfers ownership. This is sometimes helpful and sometimes leads to surprises when multiple entities think they have ownership and try to delete the same object at different times, which could lead to ... a segmentation violation.

Comment: Why do we need to set a bounty? I already answered the question. Please read answer 2 why I submitted in the last 17 hours. Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling the authors of `NFA` and `auto_vector` are getting something wrong here. Why are the members pointers? You should take advantage of RAII; this is precisely where C++ excels over other languages! You have the guarantee that when a valid automatic object goes out of scope its destructor will be called, regardless of wether the stack rewinds due to an exception or the stack unrolls cleanly. Take advantage of this guarantee!

For starters, throw away that `aut_vector` class. You don't need it. Use a `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T> >`. As an automatic member, not a pointer member, of course. Then remove the destructor; you don't need it.

There, you eliminated a full-blown *class* and a destructor. If you had a copy-constructor, which you should have had, and an assignment operator, which you should have had as well, and a swap member, which would have been an excellent idea to have, then you could eliminate these too. That's a lot of code eliminated and a lot of correctness achieved. Two birds, one stone.

Comment: @wilhemtell, I agree with your boost::shared_ptr<T> approach. Howewer we have tried the boost regex class  before and boost  requires the latest Solaris IBM AIX and HPUX UNIX licenses. We are still waiting for approval for all the UNIX licenses. Is there a possible workaround until we obtain approval for the licenses? I like the idea of an automatic member variable. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Just use the `shared_ptr` part of Boost.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have solved the segmentation fault problem. It occured when memory allocated with malloc was deallocated with delete, thereby corrupting the heap. I replaced all the malloc's with the new operator. The reason the malloc was mismatched with delete was because the python to C++ converter program used the Boehm garbage collector. We are taking out the Boehm garbage collector and replacing it with new and delete. The Boehm garbage collector has two disadvantages, First, it pauses at random  times during garbage collection. Second, it has a finite amount of heap memory which can only be changed at compile time. As a result, it has scalability issues with large applications.
The auto_vector class runs Okay. I tested it with Valgrind and there were no major problems. The memory leak has been addressed. Thank you for all the Boost suggestions.
```